# Mapping and renaming image file names/label from CSV

Tags: python, image, csv

I have csv file which contain image name like 1.jpg,2.jpg and another column contain new labels like cat.jpg, dog.jpg . my folder of images contain filenames/labels as 1.jpg and 2.jpg and want to rename them by referencing the csv file. Can someone give tips how to do it using python .

```
import os.path
import csv
current_directory =  os.path.dirname(__file__)
csv_file_path = os.path.join(current_directory,'labels.csv')
with open(csv_file_path, 'r') as f:
    lines = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
    for line in lines:        
        current_file_path = os.path.join(current_directory,line[0])
        renamed_file_path = os.path.join(current_directory,line[1] + ".png")
        os.rename(current_file_path, renamed_file_path)
```

I tried this but its not helping me.

Comment: Read the CSV line by line. Get the existing and the new name. Call `os.rename()`. Try writing some code and clicking `edit` under your question to share it if you get stuck. Good luck.

Comment: Can you check whats wrong in this code

Comment: How should I rename my image files now ? https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell

Comment: You're getting there, well done. Please provide some sample lines from your CSV and a better explanation of *"it's not helping"*. Are there error messages? Is it running at all? Is it doing something but the wrong thing?

Comment: You alert other Stack Overflow users by `@Username`.

Comment: yeah sure. So currently its not renaming my image files by new name as per code @Mark Setchell

Comment: Try putting a debug statement in there above the `os.rename()` that says `print(f'current: {current_file_path}, new: {renamed_file_path}')` I still don't see a sample `labels.csv` file by the way.